# Renting a car in one country and return it in another one (Europe)

Tags: germany, europe, italy, car-rentals, denmark

I would like to rent a car in Denmark (Copenhagen), travel for a few days (less than a week) and return it in Italy (or in Germany, like Munich for example).

Is it possible to do something like that? Are there any companies specialized in these sort of things? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: If possible at all, it will be _very_ expensive - the car is registered and insured in the starting country, and cannot simply be re-rented out in the target country. Someone (working for the rental company) has to drive it back, and fly home, and get paid time and expenses, so you have an idea what the minimum is.

Comment: The cheaper option is to rent from somewhere in the north of Germany drive and drop of in the south of Germany.

Comment: There e.g. runs a train from Copenhagen to Hamburg, and in Hamburg there is at least one car rental at the main station, if I remember correctly. Or you could cross by ferry to Kiel and rent a car there. Buchbinder is a rather cheap, reliable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do something like that?

Yes, e.g. https://www.hertz.com/:

[image]

> Is there anything I should be aware of?

The drop fee. https://www.enterprise.com/en/help/faqs/car-rental-drop-charge.html:

> A drop charge is a fee for picking up a rental car at one location and returning it to a different location. The rental car drop fee varies depending on location and ...

[image]

FYI: [Can I still rent a car through Hertz that filed for bankruptcy?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/159074/1810)

Note I didn't try to minimize the price.  Other car rentals companies might be cheaper.